# removing icons in applications

Tags: appmenu

Using Ubuntu 18.04 and some icons are showing in the applications window that were from an uninstalled program, how can those be removed??
Also have an Icon there that says "Healthy Comp" on it but when clicking on it, the computer messes up and have to manually shutdown and restart to get working right again.  I don't know what that is for or how it got there, how can it be removed??

Answer (score 0):

Icons in the application overview (or in the menu on other desktop environments) correspond to desktop launchers installed in specific folders of your system. These desktop launchers are text files with the `.desktop` extension.

The uninstall process of an application should automatically remove also the launchers of these programs. You may find out where a certain `.desktop` file is installed with a seach:

```
find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H "Healthy Comp" {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

This would find such files containing "Healthy Comp". Deleting the file (elevated permissions may be needed) will remove it from the Application overview.

There is a caveat, though. The Application overview will not show `.desktop` files where the executable, specified on the `Exec=` line, is invalid. That you still see some of these icons might mean that your application was not properly uninstalled, i.e., the name of the executable still is to be found on your system.

If you know the name of the executable from the `Exec=` line in the desktop launcher, you can see if and where it is on the system with the command `which <name of executable>`.